# New Cookies aren't Showing Up with Java Servlets/Tomcat after removing Cookies from Chrome

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cookies

I am new at Java. I saw some responses but didn't quite got it, something with doFilter or Wrapper. I am inside a @WebServlet running this code after cleaning the Chrome Cookies, but it always print 'Sorry', although I just created a new Cookie.

```
    @WebServlet(name = "Servlet2",
            urlPatterns = "/welcome")
    public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//some code here
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("Session-Cookie-", "Cookie-Value-S");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            if (cookies == null) {
                System.out.println("SORRY");
            } else {
                System.out.println("OHYEAH");
            }
//some code here
        }
    }
```

How can I implement a code to deal with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you write `request.getCookies()`  its giving request for the same page that's the reason cookies still doesn't exist . Test this code in some redirected page and see there it will work.

Comment: Yes. If i redirect to client it works. If I redirect to another Servlet it still does not. I was looking for a way to refresh maybe the Servlet but not to run all the code that comes before the creation of the Cookie up to after it.

Comment: How about setting some Attribute in session and checking if it exist or not i.e : `if(condtion){ //creating cookies}else{ //refresh}` i have not tried this thing but this should work maybe.

Comment: Yes. But would be helpful it there was a better way to do it. Thanks anyways!